# PHP Extract only id value from a content

Tags: php, regex

I am having a content

```
 through the pictures he captures, he expresses what he feels about a subject, be it a wedding shoot or couple’s portraits, by capturing emotions in its true essence. Pre-wedding shoots have unveiled to him numerous love stories in unimaginable ways. Every wedding is a different story yet with the same energy, colors and happy spirits all over. What he loves about all this is that he can help people beautify their memories and capture the best ones.</p>
<p><strong>Contact details:</strong></p>
<p>Mobile: +91 90496 80434<br>Email: <a href="mailto:ashishlangade@gmail.com">ashishlangade@gmail.com</a><br>Facebook page: <a href="https://www.facebook.com/AshishLangadePhotography">www.facebook.com/AshishLangadePhotography</a><br>Instagram page: <a href="https://www.instagram.com/3three.little.words/?hl=en">www.instagram.com/3three.little.words</a></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<!-- wp:imagely/nextgen-gallery -->
  [ngg src="galleries" ids="568" display="basic_thumbnail"]
  <!-- /wp:imagely/nextgen-gallery -->
```

From that content i need only value 568.

Comment: You should already know that you are supposed to show your own efforts, have you done anything yet? Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and 
[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can either parse the html using `domdocument`. Or you could extract it with a regex.

```
preg_match ( '/ids="(\d+)"/', $subject $aOut);
var_dump($aOut);
```

As kerbholz said, unless you are consuming this data as a string and trying to parse it, you should already have the id.